# Sending email issue in Amazon EC2 with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

My goal: email form page - if the user presses send it has to send the email to the admin account

ok i followed the rails tutorial.

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'google.com',
    user_name:            'MYACCOUNT',
    password:             'MYPAASSWORD',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
```

setup like this,

and it works perfect! in my local host

but if i deploy to amazon ec2. it doesn't work, but the nginx server logs says no error :(

```
Processing by IndexController#send_email as */*
App 2705 stderr:   Parameters: {"contactName"=>"asfsdf", "email"=>"asdf@asdf.net", "comments"=>"asdf", "submitted"=>"true"}
App 2705 stderr: 
App 2705 stderr: Sent mail to MYEMAIL@gmail.com (10.9ms)
App 2705 stderr: Date: Sat, 22 Feb 2014 01:49:08 +0000
App 2705 stderr: From: asdf@asdf.net
App 2705 stderr: Reply-To: asdf@asdf.net
App 2705 stderr: To: MYEMAIL@gmail.com
App 2705 stderr: Message-ID: <53080214b6e70_aa42499f8854356@ip-172-31-23-192.mail>
App 2705 stderr: Subject: asfsdf***** MAIL FROM MY SITE******
App 2705 stderr: Mime-Version: 1.0
App 2705 stderr: Content-Type: text/plain;
App 2705 stderr:  charset=UTF-8
App 2705 stderr: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

i think this is not a code issue, cuz this is working fine in my local

i think that i have to setup the configuration some where in ec2

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of potential issues here:

---

**Production**

Are your SMTP settings (detailed in question) in your `development.rb`? This would mean they are only registered for when your application is running in the development environment

This is common mistake, and can be resolved by either applying the same code in `config/environments/production.rb` or `config/application.rb`

---

**SMTP**

Some services (Heroku being one) highly encourage the use of third-party "transactional" SMTP services behind your app. Notibly, [SendGrid](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid) and [Mandrill](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mandrill) are the two most popular

Here is working code we use with SendGrid & Heroku (Amazon):

```
  #config/environments/production.rb
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

---

**Sending**

Another problem may be how you're sending messages

Many systems (Heroku being one) have a timeout time. This is important because it means if your email takes longer than the timeout time to send, the server will automatically kill the process

A much more robust way is to use something like [`Resque & Redis`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) to queue emails, ensuring you don't timeout the request

Answer (score 0):

It is likely getting rejected by the end user as the IP has been blacklisted at Spamhaus. You shouldn't use an EC2 instance to send out email, instead use a service like Amazon SES (free from ec2 instances up to a certain number a day) or a third party vendor such as sendgrid or authsmtp.